# unable to launch server, Rails mysql2 gem, windows 7; 193: %1 is not valid win32 application error

Tags: mysql

First, I've read many other posts, and none of the solutions posted seem to be working. Not sure what im missing exactly, but in any case nothings working. Secondly, I am pretty new to the dev world, ruby, rails and programming.

I've tried copying .dlls from folders and i think i have the 64 bit version installed of my sql and ruby so not sure if thats an issue. I think my processor should be x64 bit but when I look at my system properties it only says windows os 64 bit, nothing about cpu being 64 bit. Could this be an issue? the error msg im reciving when I try to launch rails server from my rails application using:

```
c:\sites\rails s
```

I get this:

```
c:/ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.15/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `requir
e': 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.   - c:/ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2
.0.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.0.0/mysql2-0.3.15/mysql2/mysql2.so (LoadError)
```

Followed by more msg.

A few questions I have. Would I be better off installing a partition of linux and doing dev work in that? Also, I am following along with lynda ruby on rails 4 essential training and a lot of it is done on mac. Is this going to be useful being on a windows machine? Would it be easier just using the default database system instead of mysql. My whole goal right now is just to start creating and understanding simple web apps and getting familiar with how the systems work.

What other advice/comments regarding getting into web dev programming and computer tech in general. Any helpful comments greatly appreciated, thanks so much.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You're dumping a lot of information here that seems not really related to your question; please try to provide the information necessary to describe your problem, but no more. Also, stick to a *single question* - if you've got several questions, post them separately. 
Regarding your problem: is "rails s" really the complete command you're running?

Comment: understood. And yes, thats what it says to type in the lynda tutorial "rails server" or "rails s" to launch the web server, so thats what im doing.

Comment: ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22) [x64-mingw32] , rails 4.0.2, my sql connector c 6.1.3, my sql server 5.3, gems 2.2.2